# Cell References not being converted from RC format to A1 format for formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I can find a lot about actually doing the conversion, but I have a loop that consists of an if statement with 20 potential formulas, ending in:

```
    ElseIf f = "weightVolume" Then
        Range(Cells(2, e), Cells(lastRow, e)).Formula = _
            "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC1,RC2,SUBSTITUTE(R1C,LEFT(R1C,SEARCH(""_"",R1C)),"""")),Transform!C8:C26,19,FALSE),"""")"

    ElseIf f = "Location" Then
        Range(Cells(2, e), Cells(lastRow, e)).Formula = _
            "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC1,RC2),Transform!C1:C28,29,FALSE),""Unhandled Error"")"

     Else
         Range(Cells(2, e), Cells(lastRow, e)).Value = "Unhandled Error"

     End If
```

All of the preceeding 19 formulas work like a charm, going into the sheet as:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($A2,$B2,SUBSTITUTE(KH$1,LEFT(KH$1,SEARCH("_",KH$1)),"")),Transform!$H:$Z,19,FALSE),"")
```

But the last one is going into the sheet as:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC1,RC2),Transform!C1:C28,29,FALSE),"Unhandled Error")
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the final formula is being entered with:

```
RC1,RC2
```

Has anyone encountered anything similar? Did I bork the syntax in the last formula in some way?

I have been staring at this for an hour and a half and I for the life of me cannot understand what is happening.

Comment: Use `FormulaR1C1` instead of `Formula` if you are entering formulas in R1C1 notation.  Otherwise Excel has to guess what you are doing, and `C1:C28` is probably making it think that last formula is A1 notation.  It's probably dependent on how far into the formula it looks in making its decision.  Or it might be based on whether there are more things that look R1C1-ish than look A1-ish.

Comment: If you could submit an answer that is just my bit of code with "R1C1" added to it, I can upvote it, mark it as the answer, and silently thank you for teaching me the bloody difference between the 2. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `FormulaR1C1` instead of `Formula` when using formulas in R1C1 notation.

i.e. use:

```
ElseIf f = "weightVolume" Then
    Range(Cells(2, e), Cells(lastRow, e)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC1,RC2,SUBSTITUTE(R1C,LEFT(R1C,SEARCH(""_"",R1C)),"""")),Transform!C8:C26,19,FALSE),"""")"

ElseIf f = "Location" Then
    Range(Cells(2, e), Cells(lastRow, e)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC1,RC2),Transform!C1:C28,29,FALSE),""Unhandled Error"")"

 Else
     Range(Cells(2, e), Cells(lastRow, e)).Value = "Unhandled Error"

 End If
```

When entering a formula using `Formula`, Excel will sometimes pick up that it has been written in R1C1 notation rather than A1 notation, and will convert it accordingly.  But sometimes its "guess" as to which notation you are using is tricked by the presence of references that could be treated correctly in either notation (such as your `C1:C28`).